# Styling multiple navbars css

Tags: html, css, styles, navbar

I've got two navbars here and I'm trying to put one on top of the other with no success. I'm just learning how to style and it's more difficult than I thought. Thanks for any answers.

[image: Navbar]

```
div.IntroduceYourself nav,
div.IntroduceYourself nav ul,
div.IntroduceYourself nav li div.IntroduceYourself nav a {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    line-height: 1;

}

div.IntroduceYourself nav ul li.category{
    float: left;
}

div.IntroduceYourself nav ul li {
    float: right;
}




div.Stories nav,
div.Stories nav ul,
div.Stories nav li div.Stories nav a {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    line-height: 1;

}

div.Stories nav ul li.category{
    float: left;
}

div.Stories nav ul li {
    float: right;
}
```

And here is the HTML code..

```
<div class="IntroduceYourself">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="category"><a href='/Forum/IntroduceYourself'>Introduce Yourself</a></li>
            <!-- Need a better way of adding spaces.. -->
            <li class="recentpost">
                <a href='/blog/{{ recent_intro.id }}'>Most recent post: {{ recent_intro.title }}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="totalposts"><p>Number of replies: {{ total_intro }}</p></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="Stories">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="category"><a href='/Forum/Stories'>Share Stories</a></li>
            <li>
                {#% for intro in introduce_list %#}
                <a href='/blog/{{ recent_story.id }}'>Most recent story: {{ recent_story.title }}</a>
                {#% endfor %#}
            </li>
            <li><p>Number of replies: {{ total_stories }}</p></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Div.class should be separated with a space like div .class

Comment: When I separate it with a space the styling no longer works.

Comment: Ah I was blind to the problem, don't make it div .class just make it .class because div .class means a class inside of a division, not a division with that class name.

Comment: Do you want them that spread out you floating menu items all over the place.its over complicated. Set body width to 100%. Then set your two menu divs width to100% and float left. Finally add display : inline block to the list items